# hive auto increment after certain number

Tags: hive

I have a to insert data into a  target table where all columns should be populated from different source tables except the surrogate key column; which should be maximum value of the target table plus auto increment value starting 1. I can generate auto increment value by using row_number() function, but in the same query how should I get the max value of surrogate key from target table. Is there any concept in HIVE where I can select the max value of surrogate key and save it in a temporary variable? Or is there any other simple way to achieve this result?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here are two approaches which worked for me for the above problem. ( explained with example)

**Approach 1:** getting the max and setting to hive commands  through ${hiveconf} variable using shell script

**Approach 2:** using row_sequence(), max() and join operations

**My Environment:**

```
hadoop-2.6.0
apache-hive-2.0.0-bin
```

**Steps:** (**note:** step 1 and step 2 are common for both approaches. Starting from step 3 , it differs for both)

**Step 1:** create source and target tables

**source**

```
hive>create table source_table1(string name);
hive>create table source_table2(string name);
hive>create table source_table2(string name);
```

**target**

```
hive>create table target_table(int id,string name);
```

**Step 2:** load data into source tables

```
hive>load data local inpath 'source_table1.txt' into table source_table1;
hive>load data local inpath 'source_table2.txt' into table source_table2;
hive>load data local inpath 'source_table3.txt' into table source_table3;
```

Sample Input:

source_table1.txt

```
a
b
c
```

source_table2.txt

```
d
e
f
```

source_table3.txt

```
g
h
i
```

**Approach 1:**

**Step 3:** create a shell script hive_auto_increment.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
hive -e 'select max(id) from target_table' > max.txt
wait
value=`cat max.txt`
hive --hiveconf mx=$value -e "add jar /home/apache-hive-2.0.0-bin/lib/hive-contrib-2.0.0.jar;
create temporary function row_sequence as 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.udf.UDFRowSequence';
set mx;
set hiveconf:mx;
INSERT INTO TABLE target_table SELECT row_sequence(),name from source_table1;
INSERT INTO TABLE target_table SELECT (\${hiveconf:mx} +row_sequence()),name from source_table2;
INSERT INTO TABLE target_table SELECT (\${hiveconf:mx} +row_sequence()),name from source_table3;"
wait
hive -e "select * from target_table;"
```

**Step 4:** run the shell script

```
 > bash  hive_auto_increment.sh
```

**Approach 2:**

**Step 3:** Add Jar

```
    hive>add jar /home/apache-hive-2.0.0-bin/lib/hive-contrib-2.0.0.jar;
```

**Step 4:** register row_sequence function with help of hive contrib jar

```
hive>create temporary function row_sequence as 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.udf.UDFRowSequence';
```

**Step 5:** load the source_table1 to target_table

```
hive>INSERT INTO TABLE target_table select row_sequence(),name from source_table1;
```

**Step 6:** load the other sources to target_table

```
  hive>INSERT INTO TABLE target_table SELECT M.rowcount+row_sequence(),T.name from source_table2 T join (select max(id) as rowcount from target_table) M;

  hive>INSERT INTO TABLE target_table SELECT  M.rowcount+row_sequence(),T.name from source_table3 T join (select max(id) as rowcount from target_table) M;
```

**output:**

```
INFO  : OK
+---------------+-----------------+--+
| target_table.id  | target_table.name  
+---------------+-----------------+--+
| 1                | a               |
| 2                | b               |
| 3                | c               |
| 4                | d               |
| 5                | e               |
| 6                | f               |
| 7                | g               |
| 8                | h               |
| 9                | i               |
```

Comment: Thanks for  the elaborate answer. Can you please let know what we can do in a situation where records are inserted into the target table from multiple jobs simultaneously?

Answer (score 0):

create table autoincrement1 ( id int, name string)

insert into autoincrement1
select if(isnull(max(id)) ,0 , max(id) ) +1, 'sagar' from autoincrement1

Comment: From Review:  Hi, please don't answer just with source code. Try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks