# Hive - Thread-safe auto-increment sequence number generation

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-zookeeper, distributed-computing

I have a situation where I need to insert records into a particular Hive table.

One of the columns requires to be an auto-incremented sequence number (that **has to strictly follow [max.value + 1] rule at any point of time**).

Records are inserted into this particular table from many parallel Hive jobs, that are run in batches - daily, weekly, monthly.

Now, I have these questions:

1. Will org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.udf.UDFRowSequence ( http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hive/trunk/contrib/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/contrib/udf/UDFRowSequence.java ) be the right
   choice?
2. How can I make it **thread-safe**, since parallel jobs are also
       involved in inserting the records?

Note: I came across this useful post ( [hive auto increment after certain number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38949699/hive-auto-increment-after-certain-number) ) which I continue to watch, but had to raise a fresh one since (1) an answer is already accepted for that question and so may possibly lose attention of the community and (2) my situation includes thread-safe sequence number generation.